# Describe listener rule count using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-automation

i need to list listener rules count but still i get a output as **null** without any error.my complete project was getting email notification from when listener rules created on elastic load balancer.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('elbv2')
    response = client.describe_listeners(
    ListenerArns=[
        'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:my_alb_listener',
    ],
)

print('response')
```

Here is the output of my code

Response
null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response is null because your indentation is incorrect and you are not returning anything from your handler. It should be:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('elbv2')
    response = client.describe_listeners(
    ListenerArns=[
        'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:my_alb_listener',
      ],
    )

    return response
```

Comment: I just used above code on Lambda function and length function to calculate listner rules. However it always return the value as 2 even ALB has more than 20 rules.

Comment: tot = len(response1)
    return response1